# Why doesn't my owl slider shows up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, owl-carousel

I'm having an issue with integrating owl-slider with a WordPress theme. The slider should get the featured image of the latest 4 posts, with the title and a small description. The problem is the output `owl-slider` shows up in the inspector but as a white-div and nothing else,

A screenshot of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNiTv.png

The code of the loop:

```
<div class="SlideShow">
    <div id="owl-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <?php
        $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=4' );
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="item">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?>
            <div class="caption">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">التفاصيل</a><!--More Link-->
                <div class="innercapt">
                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1><!--Title-->
                    <p><?php echo excerpt(9);?></p><!--Description-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;
        // Reset Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The function is being called with this code in the footer:

```
<script>
    ;(function($){
        $("#owl-slider").owlCarousel({
            autoPlay: true,
            navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
            slideSpeed : 300,
            pagination : false,
            singleItem : true
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: You need to call the Owl Carousel function after the DOM Elements are created, and be sure that they are not hidden. How are you even calling the Carousel function?

Comment: @brance Updated the question, please check it.

Comment: Can you post a link to your page, because I can't see any problem with the code. It seems that the carousel can't properly calculate the widths and heights for the slider, but I am not 100% sure if that is the problem.

Comment: @brance Here it is http://­4a91238e.ngrok.io/­ensan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add css direction ltr on the class owl-carousel
because the carousel have a bug in body direction rtl

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the JS code in document.ready like this, maybe it will work as I couldn't find anything that could cause the error.

```
;(function($){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#owl-slider").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: true,
        navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
        slideSpeed : 300,
        pagination : false,
        singleItem : true
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Could you remove the script and paste the HTML Output before the Owl redner?

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by the "redner"?

Comment: Sorry I was afk, I mean remove the script so it doesn't create the Slider, but only shows the HTML of the images and text, do you understand me now?

Comment: Just did, check it now.

Comment: The link is not working anymore if you mean it by check it now.